# Bottom overflow while having multiple line item in dropdown flutter

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu

I have multiple line items in the dropdown menu in flutter like this :

[image]

It is shown perfectly fine in the dropdown pop up but in dropdown button it shows bottomoverflow like this :

[image]

Here is code for the same :

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                                        child: DropdownButton(
                                          items: addresses.map((String value) {
                                            return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                              value: value,
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                height: 10 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
                                                child: Column(
                                                  children: [
                                                    SizedBox(height: 1.5 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                                                    new Text(value, overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
                                                    SizedBox(height: 1.5 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            );
                                          }).toList(),
                                          onChanged: (String newValue) {
                                            setState(() {
                                              _selectedShippingAddress = newValue;
                                            });
                                          },
                                          hint: Text("Select address"),
                                          selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                                            return addresses.map<Widget>((String item) {
                                              return Container(
                                                child: Text(item),
                                              );
                                            }).toList();
                                          },
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 1.9 *
                                                  SizeConfig.textMultiplier,
                                              color:
                                              Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                                          value: _selectedShippingAddress,
                                          isExpanded: true,
                                          underline: Container(
                                            height: 1,
                                            color: Theme.of(context)
                                                .textSelectionColor,
                                          ),
                                          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                                          isDense: true,
                                        ),
                                      )
```

So what is a solution for this? Can anyone help on this?

Comment: please share your code problem is ocurred.

Comment: Added the code for the same... @KuKu

Comment: can you add some of the List of String that you are showing in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

From the example that you provided I replicated it and there is a problem in the blow code

```
DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                              value: value,
                                              child: SizedBox(
                                                height: 10 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
```

Maybe the height is doing some problem just added a sample example below to let you know the things work.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SampleApp(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class SampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SampleAppState createState() => _SampleAppState();
}

class _SampleAppState extends State<SampleApp> {
  String _selectedShippingAddress;

  List addresses = ['sample1', 'sample 2'];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Your heading'),
        ),
        body: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton<String>(
            items: addresses.map((value) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: SizedBox(
                 
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      SizedBox(height: 5),
                      new Text(value, overflow: TextOverflow.clip),
                      SizedBox(height: 5),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (String newValue) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedShippingAddress = newValue;
              });
            },
            hint: Text("Select address"),
            selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return addresses.map<Widget>((item) {
                return Container(
                  child: Text(item),
                );
              }).toList();
            },
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14,
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
            value: _selectedShippingAddress,
            isExpanded: true,
            underline: Container(
              height: 1,
              color: Theme.of(context).textSelectionColor,
            ),
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            isDense: true,
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```